# How to get "Area under aircraft unsuitable for landing" message?

Tags: swift, dji-sdk

When I initiate auto-landing in the DJI Fly app I sometimes get the following message, especially under bad lighting conditions:

[image]

Now, in my own code, when I call `DJIFlightController.startLandingWithCompletion`, the drone would not land and the completion block gets executed without any error.

My question is, how can I intercept the equivalent to DJIs error message as shown above? What code is relevant for that?

EDIT 1:

I am also checking if a landing confirmation is needed with the following code:

```swift
func observeConfirmLanding() {
    guard let confirmLandingKey = DJIFlightControllerKey(param: DJIFlightControllerParamConfirmLanding) else { return }
    DJISDKManager.keyManager()?.startListeningForChanges(on: confirmLandingKey, withListener: self) { (oldValue: DJIKeyedValue?, newValue: DJIKeyedValue?) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let oldBoolValue = oldValue?.boolValue,
           let newBoolValue = newValue?.boolValue,
           oldBoolValue != newBoolValue {
               self.landingConfirmationNeeded = newBoolValue
               self.logger.debug("Landing confirmation is needed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It never enters the closure.

As I understood the landing confirmation might be needed at a height of 0.3m, but in my case, the landing process gets interrupted at different heights that are more than 0.3m, e.g. already at 2m or 1.5m

EDIT 2:

I have changed the surface below the drone in my basement by adding a bright carpet with a distinct pattern. This improves the whole stability of the drone AND even more important: The drone just lands without being interrupted. I do not get the warning message in the DJI Fly app any more.

[image]

I check for `isLandingConfirmation` the way Brien suggests in his comment, I finally get `true` when testing this in the **simulator**.

```swift
extension FlightControllerObserver: DJIFlightControllerDelegate {
    func flightController(_ fc: DJIFlightController, didUpdate state: DJIFlightControllerState) {
        if (landingConfirmationNeeded != state.isLandingConfirmationNeeded) {
            landingConfirmationNeeded = state.isLandingConfirmationNeeded
        }
}
```

But, when I test this in my basement (flight mode "OPTI") and outside (flight mode "GPS") the drone just lands without waiting for any confirmation.

While I learned a lot, it is still a miracle to me which class in the DJI Mobile SDK is responsible for "throwing" that warning message.

Answer (score 0):

If the completion handler completes without any error you might need to check if `isLandingConfirmationNeeded` in `DJIFlightControllerState` is set to `true`. If thats the case then you will need to implement the function `confirmLandingWithCompletion`.

Sounds relevant to your experience looking at the documentation

> - (void)confirmLandingWithCompletion:(DJICompletionBlock)completion Confirms continuation of landing action. When the clearance between
>   the aircraft and the ground is less than 0.3m, the aircraft will pause
>   landing and wait for user's confirmation. Can use
>   isLandingConfirmationNeeded in DJIFlightControllerState to check if
>   confirmation is needed. It is supported by flight controller firmware
>   3.2.0.0 and above.

The `landingProtectionState` property of the [DJIVisionControlState](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/IntelligentFlightAssistant/DJIVisionDetectionState_DJIVisionControlState.html#djivisiondetectionstate_djivisioncontrolstate_djivisionlandingprotectionstatus_inline) class could be a good place to look for the cause of that error message. One of the potential states that sounds relevant is

> DJIVisionLandingProtectionStateNotSafeToLand -> Landing area is not flat
> enough to be considered safe for landing. The aircraft should be moved
> to an area that is more flat and an auto-land should be attempted
> again or the user should land the aircraft manually.

Also within a section of DJI's documentation there is a section on an article about flight control that talks about [landing protection](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/guides/component-guide-flight-control.html#returning-home-and-landing) and forcing a landing. I couldn't see any functions in the SDK to force a landing.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not working either, please see EDIT 1 in my question.

Comment: You mentioned it never enters the closure. I realise the listener should trigger when the value changes, but have you checked the value of `isLandingConfirmationNeeded` when the landing is interrupted? Perhaps log the output of the `DJIFlightControllerDelegate` method `didUpdateState`

Comment: I have implemented the didUpdateState as per your recommendation, the value is changed now, but only in the simulator, not in real-life. Please see my EDIT 2.

Comment: Just updated my answer. It sounds like the vision sensor can't detect if it's safe to land. Are you looking to override the auto landing protection or just looking to present the user with an option to manually land when they encounter this issue?

Comment: The DJIVisionControlState looks like a promising candidate. I will have a look and report back.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of that the fly app does not use the sdk internally. It uses the middlelayer directly.

You often get different behaivor when using the SDK compared to the app. Some functions are not available at all.

I usually disable it completly, I want it to land when I say so :-)
(exit_landing_ground_not_smooth_enable  g_config.landing.exit_landing_ground_not_smooth_enable)